# How to remove few options from select box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove few options, say, last three options, from a select box out of 5 options, using jquery

Below is the select box with 5 options tag

```
<select id="select">
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option>
  <option>fourth</option>
  <option>fifth</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried this code

```
$("#select option:not(option:first, option:last)";
```

But that gave me uncaught exception in console

Comment: What have your tried?

Answer (score 7):

[`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method is the way to go:

```
$("#select > option").slice(-3).remove();
```

Comment: u can also add a "each" , and based on the id of option remove it ?.. that would be more generic

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? I think the [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to remove the latest items
http://jsfiddle.net/QxmvC/

```
     $('#select').children().slice(-3).remove();
```